# Rake file tasks do not work

Tags: ruby, build, rake

The below file task does not execute. It is the contents of a simple Rakefile that is meant to create a file named `hello.txt`, if it doesn't exist.

```
task :default do
    puts "before file task"
    file "hello.txt" do
        puts "in file task"
        sh "touch hello.txt"
    end
    puts "after file task"
end
```

After running `rake` at the shell prompt in the directory where the Rakefile is located, the output is:

```
before file task
after file task
```

and no `hello.txt` file is created.

I am unsure as to why the file task does not work, as to my eye the syntax of the file task portion of the Rakefile looks sound. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

When you call the `default`-task it does three things

1. write *before file task*
2. define the file task 'hello.txt'
3. write *after file task*

To repeat the important thing: The file task *hello.txt* is **defined**, not **executed**

Maybe you want to do something like:

```
task :default do
    puts "before file creation"
    File.open("hello.txt","w") do |f|
        puts "in file creation"
        f << "content for hello.txt"
    end
    puts "after file creation"
end
```

This creates the file always.

You may also use the method in [pyotr6 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17883437/676874):

```
task :default => 'hello.txt' do
    puts "default task, executed after prerequistes"
end

file 'hello.txt' do |tsk|
  File.open(tsk.name, "w") do |f|
    puts "in file creation of #{f.path}"
    f << "content for hello.txt"
  end
end
```

This would create hello.txt once. If hello.txt already exists, the file task will not start.

To regenerate hello.txt you need a prerequsite (normally this is another file, which is the source for hello.txt).

You can force a regeneration with a dummy task:

```
task :force #Dummy task to force file generation
file 'hello.txt' => :force
```

Answer (score 1):

The file task must be called or referenced directly as a regular task method would. E.g.

```
task :default => "hello.txt" do
    puts "after file task"
end

file "hello.txt" do
    puts "in file task"
    sh "touch hello.txt"
end
```

Comment: Rake includes the FileUtils module. So you're able to use the `mkdir`, `rmdir`, `cp`, `mv`, `chmod` and `touch` methods :) So `sh "touch hello.txt"` gives the same result as `touch "hello.txt"` but the latter doesn't shell out